# lexical scoping and nested functions in eval(parse())

Tags: r, closures, eval, lexical-scope

I am having trouble with [drake issue 35](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/35), and I have reproduced a minimal version of the bug for this SO post. Briefly, I want `eval(parse())` to work with nested functions, nontrivial closures, and a custom environment. I will consider the problem solved if `eval(parse(text = "f(1:10)"), envir = e)` below returns `2:11` with no errors or warnings.

```
e = new.env(parent = globalenv())
e$f = Vectorize(function(x) g(x), "x")
e$g = function(x) x + 1
eval(parse(text = "f(1:10)"), envir = e)
```

> Error in (function (x)  : could not find function "g"

```
environment(e$f) = environment(e$g) = e
eval(parse(text = "f(1:10)"), envir = e)
```

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
>         object 'vectorize.args' not found

**EDIT**

In the real world, `f` and `g` are user-defined, so I should keep the bodies of these functions as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attach` to attach the objects of `e` environment and call the function `f`.

```
e = new.env(parent = globalenv())
e$f = Vectorize(function(x) g(x), "x")
e$g = function(x) x + 1
attach(e)
search()
eval(parse(text='f(1:10)'))
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
detach(e)
search()
```

Comment: I really wish I could do that, but in the real world, `f` and `g` are user-defined. It is an unavoidable part of what `drake` is trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's okay, I did not fully lay out the constraints of the problem. The edit to the OP should help.

Comment: I just mention `drake` because otherwise people will criticize the premise of using `eval(parse())`.

Comment: That looks much more promising, but I am still getting `Error in g(x) : could not find function "g"`. I tried your idea R 3.3.3 and 3.4.0 on Red Hat Linux 4.4.7-16 and R 3.3.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: That's the weird part. I started with a fresh workspace every time. Not even an auto-loaded `.RData` file.

Comment: Aha! That just might work for the package. Thank you!

Comment: Note: it is not best practice to use attach an object or environment. Please use it with caution, because of possible naming collisions

Comment: Yes. Fortunately, I only have a single environment to attach, so I should be able to manage.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I just want to add another approach to the same idea that does not rely on `attach()`.

```
e = new.env(parent = globalenv())
eval(parse(text='f <- Vectorize(function(x) g(x), "x")'), envir = e)
eval(parse(text='g <- function(x) x + 1'), envir = e)
e2 = list2env(as.list(e), parent = e)
eval(parse(text = "f(1:10)"), envir = e2)
```

> [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11